# Equilibrium in system of non-linear difference equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a little question. I want to know if there is a process in which I can find equilibrium solutions to some system of difference equations. For example, if I have something crazy like
\begin{cases} 
x[n+1]=(x[n])^2y[n]+z[n]e^{-ax[n]}
\\[3mm] 
y[n+1]= z[n]x[n]+x[n+1]y[n+1]
\\[2mm] 
z[n+1]= \dfrac{x[n]}{1+x[n]}
\end{cases}
I would like to know how to calculate equilibrium points when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

To find the equilibrium for the system
\begin{align*} 
x[n+1] &=(x[n])^2y[n]+z[n]e^{-ax[n]},
\\[3mm] 
y[n+1] &= z[n]x[n]+x[n+1]y[n+1], \mbox{ and }
\\[2mm] 
z[n+1] &= \dfrac{x[n]}{1+x[n]} \\ 
\end{align*}
of equations, set 
\begin{align*} 
x[n+1] &= x[n]=x_*, \\ 
y[n+1] &= y[n]=y_*, \\ 
z[n+1] &= z[n]=z_*. \\ 
\end{align*} 
Then the system of equations becomes
\begin{align*} 
x_* &=x_*^2 y_*+ z_* e^{-a x_*},
\\[3mm] 
y_* &= z_* x_* + x_* y_*,
\\[2mm] 
z_* &= \dfrac{x_*}{1+x_*}. \\ 
\end{align*}
For simplicity, you can remove the lower stars and write $x = x_*$, $y = y_*$, and $z = z_*$ to obtain:
\begin{align*} 
x &=x^2 y+ z e^{-a x}, \hspace{6mm} \clubsuit
\\[3mm] 
y &= z x + x y,   \hspace{6mm} \diamondsuit
\\[2mm] 
z &= \dfrac{x}{1+x}. \hspace{6mm} \spadesuit \\ 
\end{align*}
The final step to find the equilibrium points is to solve for $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that the three equations $\clubsuit$, $\diamondsuit$, and $\spadesuit$ are satisfied.